Is it possible to create a background color for the different parts of a struktogramm?
I wanted to know if anyone had an elegant solution for having a background color for each type of command: if blocks and the "yes" "no" options are red, while blocks are blue etc.. (if possible..).
A basic example (I use beamer):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{struktex}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
        \begin{struktogramm}(100,50)
            \while{for i:= n down to 2}
            \while{for j:= 2 up to i}
            \ifthenelse[15]{2}{2}{$(A[j-1] \geq A[j]$}{yes}{no}
            \assign{tausche \(A[j-1]\) mit \(A[j]\)}
            \change
            \ifend
            \assign{mbox{}\hfil print (A)}
            \whileend
            \whileend
        \end{struktogramm}
        \end{frame}
    \end{document}


You could patch the struktex.sty to your own version and add color definitions in there. It uses \framebox for the command boxes, so you could e.g. patch code lines 283ff in struktex.sty
\ifx#21%
    \put(\x@nss,\y@nss){%
        \framebox(\xsize@nss,\ydepth@nss){\box\TextBox@nss}%
    }%

to
  \ifx#21%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \put(\x@nss,\y@nss){%
        \colorbox{yellow!20}{\framebox(\xsize@nss,\ydepth@nss){\box\TextBox@nss}}%
    }%

and accordingly for each command type and color you want.
Edit:
In accordance with the comment of user Mensch, I strongly recommend to copy the original struktex.sty (or to compile it from a source) and rename it e.g. to my-colored-struktex.sty before you apply your patches to this copy. By this, you clearly distinguish your patched package from the original one.
Patching of the original struktex.sty in your LaTeX repository would be a volatile solution, since package updates will overwrite your patches.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please note that one should never change an original file, better is to copy and rename it and change the renamed file or to use patch command in your own TeX code!

Thanks a lot, I did copy and renamed the struktex.sty file. Unfortunately, I never did that before (modify packages), so I'm not familiar with the syntax :|. I tried to copy your example for the while command and modified line 616 like this (same color just to check)
\def\whileend{%   \endstr@kt\tempy@nss=\y@nss\advance\tempy@nss by-\ydepth@nss   \y@nss=\ydepth@nss   \put(\x@nss,\y@nss){\colorbox{yellow!20}{\framebox(\xsize@nss,\tempy@nss){}}}%   \dbgString@nss{Ende \string\whileend} }
but it's not working. I don't know if I should just ask for each case how it should be done..


[...] it's not working.

Providing your actual error would help answering.
However, I see the problem from your patch. It's visible by patching code lines 615ff to
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\def\whileend{\endstr@kt\tempy@nss=\y@nss\advance\tempy@nss by-\ydepth@nss\y@nss=\ydepth@nss\put(\x@nss,\y@nss){\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}\colorbox{yellow!20}{\framebox(\xsize@nss,\tempy@nss){}}}\dbgString@nss{Ende \string\whileend}}
The opacity \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5} shows that these boxes are stacked. This is done (on top) after the text boxes are created.

Sorry, I didn't think of adding the error... I was looking for a way to color each block independently, but I also expected that coloring a “while” block would color everything in it, and unfortunately that's not what I want... But I'll keep testing what's possible to do that way. Thanks!
